# Examples of using $http.put in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Are there any simple examples of using the `$http.put` method in Angular? Specifically, I'm unsure about what the `data/Request content` parameter should be, should it be an object or an object property?

```
$http.put(url, data, [config]);
```

Comment: $http.put method is used for updating the data in the server. i.e., If you are having students' records, then using their ID, you can edit (or) update the data.  '$http.put('Some-api/students/'+stuId+'/'+data);

Comment: @VirtualRealist in your example, what is "+data"? I'm trying to understand [how to write params in the path of the http.put request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242613/how-to-use-path-parameters-in-http-put-request]).  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second parameter must be an object:

```
$http.put('/api/v1/users/' + user.login, { login: "login", password: "password" });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use $http.put like this in my project.

```
$http.put(api/resources/:id, {name:name});
```