# How to use path parameters in http.put request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, put, path-parameter

I want to know how to write the `PUT` request that sends parameters in the path. For example, dev changed the URL for the PUT request from a using a query string as parameters to using parameters in the path. When params were sent as query, I did something like this:

```
let payload = {
   product_id: this.productId,
   customer_id: this.customerId,
   userGuide_id: this.userGuide
}

return this._$q((resolve, reject) => {
   this._$http.put(‘/api/products/customer/mostRecent’, payload)
   .then((result) => resolve(result))
   .catch((err) => {
      reject(…));
   });
});
```

Easy.

However, now that the PUT request is changed to use params in the path i.e.:

```
PUT api/products/customer/{customerId}/product/{productId}
```

How exactly would I write that?

```
let customer_id = this.customerId,
    product_id = this.productId;

let payload = {
    user_GuideId: this.userGuideId
}

this._$http.put(“api/products/”+customer_id+“/product/”+product_id, payload);
```

The above is probably wrong since I don't know how to do this. I appreciate the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The above is normal way...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov so my code is correct?

Comment: If it works - yes) I mean there is nothing complicated here - you can combine url in whatever way you like. If you use es6 you can use ${} notation like in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
this._$http.put(`api/products${customerId}/product/${productId}`, payload);
```

Note: I am using Template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Thank you!

Updated:

```
let payload = {
   product_id: this.productId,
   customer_id: this.customerId,
   userGuide_id: this.userGuide
}

return this._$q((resolve, reject) => {
   this._$http.put(`api/products${payload.customer_id}/product/${payload.product_id}`, payload);
   .then((result) => resolve(result))
   .catch((err) => {
      reject(…));
   });
});
```

Comment: how would I add the payload -- as additional data is also required, but not as a parameter in the path.

Comment: @Chris22 I updated my answer. thank you and let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: I just updated it again, please take a look -- thank you!

Comment: thanks very much! I accidentally left out the `/` at the end of `api/products` before the first templated parameter -- should be `api/products/` sorry! Oh, one question, you are accessing the parameters off of the `payload` object even though they aren't defined in that object?  If so,  should I put everything in the payload object instead of declaring them separately?  I have not tested the new api yet ... so adding the `payload` object at the end makes me think that `customer_id` and `product_id` would be sent twice... is that correct or would it create an error?

Comment: @Chris22 Hi,

You are welcome anytime!

" Oh, one question, you are accessing the parameters off of the payload object even though they aren't defined in that object?"
I have updated my answer which also includes the payload object. In this payload object :
`   product_id: this.productId,
   customer_id: this.customerId,` are defined, or did you mean something else?

Comment: " should I put everything in the payload object instead of declaring them separately?"
"so adding the payload object at the end makes me think that customer_id and product_id would be sent twice"

So by putting in payload + using them in parameters it would be like sending twitce, 1 through parameter and 2nd through payload object.

"is that correct or would it create an error?"
Even if you send more than once it shouldn't give error in most cases.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question about `payload` object properties.  Yes, that is what I meant:  assigning the `product_id` and `customer_id` as properties within the payload object since that is how you shaped those parameters in the path.  I see that you updated your code adding the payload object with those properties.  Thank you!